# Is "snoot" really a word? Where did it originate?

Tags: etymology

I have seen the word (or term) "snoot" defined as a person who is punctilious about words, grammar, punctuation, pronunciation, and allied linguistic skills. I'm told that snoot is less off-putting than such pejorative terms as grammar nazi, word nerd, syntax snob, or language police. David Foster Wallace called those terms "outright dysphemisms" and defined a snoot as "somebody who knows what dysphemism means and doesn't mind letting you know it." See Wallace, ["Tense Present," Harper's, Apr. 2001, at 39.](http://harpers.org/wp-content/uploads/HarpersMagazine-2001-04-0070913.pdf)(PDF)

But is snoot a real word or a coined term, and if the latter, how was it coined?

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=snoot&searchmode=none

Comment: @mplungjan: etymonline.com has *snoot* meaning "the nose" but not in the sense asked about.

Comment: I disagree - from _snooty (adj.) "proud, arrogant," 1918, noted that year as college slang, from snoot_ it is a no-brainer to understand _a snoot_

Comment: @mplungjan since *snooty* comes from *snoot* in that sense, you are ultimately in agreement.

Comment: I do not agree with the "not in the sense asked about"

Comment: @mplungjan a sorry, I misread Hugo's comment.

Comment: OED ***snoot*** *[Probably a back-formation < **snooty** adj.] One who is snooty; a snob. Also occas., snootiness. colloq.*

Answer (score 7):

It's hilarious how many things Wallace gets wrong in that article, precisely because his "snooty" tone makes otherwise minor mistakes that one should probably forgive a target of schadenfreude: Live by the snoot, die by the snoot.

It generally means one who condescends, and comes from a Scots variant of *snout* meaning "nose", as in "looking down ones nose", via *snooty*. Wallace's use is certainly a valid use as a hyponym of the general meaning, but he is incorrect in defining it specifically only for that, or for suggesting it is a coinage of his mother's (unless she was around in the 19th Century).

Comment: I'd always assumed *snooty* people were called that because they went around with their [noses in the air](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/with+nose+in+the+air), and not because they looked down their noses. But your derivation makes sense, too, and it's not clear there's any way to determine which is the right one (if a "right one" exists).

Comment: I've heard the word "snoot" used quite often to refer to the nose. (I guess I do live in a dialect area heavily influenced by the Scots Irish). One common use is to refer to someone getting a "snoot full" of something. Usually some kind of intoxicating beverage. It seems like a weird phrase, as drinking through your nose ought to be quite unpleasant, but I hear it a lot. By implication, a "snooty" person is someone who turns up their nose in an attempt to ignore others a lot.

Comment: @PeterShor Could well be related to both, as indeed "noses in the air" and "looking down ones nose" are related, the former allowing one to do the latter.

Comment: @JonHanna - Exactly. I don't know the actual etymology of the terms, but that's how I've always rationalized them.

Comment: @T.E.D. as someone who lived in a dialect so heavily influenced by the Scots Irish we don't even call them Scots Irish (as in, actually from northern Ireland where they're called Ulster Scots), I would agree; *snoot* for "nose" is definitely found, and seems to be slightly more likely to be heard from someone with a Protestant background than Catholic (the truth is that we're pretty much all a mix of Ulster Scots and pre-Plantation Irish, but we like to live with the pretence that we're two very separate peoples who have always hated each other).

Comment: I find that surprising, considering that the Scots Irish in this country are renowned for [their peace-loving nature](http://www.amazon.com/Born-Fighting-Scots-Irish-Shaped-America/dp/0767916891). ;-)

Comment: @T.E.D. yes, and so much so the other lot. Though don't dare suggest that this makes them in any way similar to each other!